# Set new value for SQL (select Max value)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not good in English… please help me…
In `SQL Server 2005`, I have a table `Total(PhoneNumber, Money, City)`
There are many the same records with the same `PhoneNumber` but different `City` and `Money` value.
Now I want to set value for `NewCity` column by: `select Max Money` (max money in the records which having same `PhoneNumber` ) in record.
How can I do that?
Please help me…

For Example:

```
PhoneNumber  City   Money   NewCity
0949000000   CTA    20      NULL
0945777777   VTH    35      NULL
0949000000   VTH    30      NULL
0945777777   VTY    120     NULL
0949000000   VTY    60      NULL
```

Comment: Please show desired results for that example data. I presume you want to set `NewCity` to the `City` value that the row with the `Max(Money)` for that `PhoneNumber` has? Not to `Max(Money)` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want to set `NewCity` to the `City` value that the row with the `Max(Money)` for that `PhoneNumber` has. (Rather than to the numeric `Max(Money)`)

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneNumber 
                              ORDER BY Money DESC) AS RN
FROM YourTable       
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN City END) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY PhoneNumber) AS _NewCity
FROM T1       
)
UPDATE T2
SET NewCity = _NewCity
```

If my assumption is wrong and you do in fact want exactly what the question states this is simpler.

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(money) OVER (partition BY PhoneNumber) Mx
         FROM   YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET    NewCity = Mx
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
update t 
set NewCity=(select MAX(money) from YourTable b where b.PhoneNumber=t.PhoneNumber)
from  YourTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to view the newcity column if you don't have the newcity column in your total table and only view the max(money) on total table and group by on duplicated table.

```
select a.*,b.newcity from total a
join (select phonenumber,city, max(money) as newcity
      from total group by phonenumber,city) b on b.phonenumber = a.phonenumber 
                                            and b.city = a.city
where a.money = b.newcity
```